Vite not loading values defined in .env
Context: Using React/Typescript/Vite/Yarn
I have a project where I am defining my backend URL in my .env file to use as a constant throughout my project.  However, it's not being recognized at the top level and I'm not sure why.  My frontend is running on port 3036 and my backend is running on port 8080, but no matter what I do, the frontend is making requests to localhost:3036.
For example, I have my .env file like this (which is in the root directory):
NODE_ENV=development
VITE_BACKEND_URL=http://localhost:8080

I originally had it just as BACKEND_URL, but through my troubleshooting I saw that a solution was to prefix it with VITE.  This did not solve the issue.
I also followed the instructions in the documentation here and put this in my vite.config.ts file:
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => {
  // Load env file based on `mode` in the current working directory.
  // Set the third parameter to '' to load all env regardless of the `VITE_` prefix.
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), '')
  return {
    // vite config
    define: {
      VITE_BACKEND_URL: JSON.stringify(env.VITE_BACKEND_URL),
    },
  }
})

However, this did not work either.
Here is where I load it in:
const {
  NODE_ENV,
  VITE_BACKEND_URL,
} = process.env;

console.log('BACKEND_URL from process.env:', VITE_BACKEND_URL)

const env = {
  NODE_ENV: NODE_ENV || 'development',
  BACKEND_URL: VITE_BACKEND_URL,
};

export type ProjectEnv = typeof env;

export default () => ({
  data: env,
});

I saw in my troubleshooting that perhaps I needed to use import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_URL but when I do that it says that import.meta.env is undefined, which I have no idea why, and the same with process.env which is giving me BACKEND_URL from process.env: undefined 
For context, here is how I use the backend url to make requests:
export const baseClient = (
  accessToken?: string | null,
  baseURL: string = '',
): AxiosInstance => {
  const headers: Record<string, string> = {};

  if (accessToken) {
    headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
  }

  return axios.create({
    // When BACKEND_URL is set, always use it.
    baseURL: isURL(BuildConfig.BACKEND_URL) ? BuildConfig.BACKEND_URL : baseURL,
    headers,
    transformResponse: [maybeParseJSON],
  });
};

export default (getState: () => RootState, authType: string = 'user'): AxiosInstance => {
  const state = getState();
  const accessToken = getToken(state, authType);
  const me = state.me;
  const baseURL = me ? getAuthBaseURL(state, me) : '';

  return baseClient(accessToken, baseURL);
};


When I run this:
NODE_ENV="development" BACKEND_URL="http://localhost:8080" yarn build
NODE_ENV="development" BACKEND_URL="http://localhost:8080" yarn dev 

It works as expected (minus some CORS issues that I haven't dealt with yet), but it looks like it uses the BACKEND_URL properly, so I'm thinking its something wrong at the top-most level where the .env file is being loaded by vite.
Also, when I echo $VITE_BACKEND_URL it outputs what I expect too, but only after i run source .env.
I'm kind of at a loss here, any help would be appreciated.

I had a look through and the vite.config.ts looks like I have it in my project. I tend to use nodemon or docker compose to set environment variables, you can also do it in the package.json. I've never used yarn, but suspect that you're right that the variables aren't being set correctly. How are you intending to load the environment variables from your .env file?

@a2k42 I was under the assumption that the loadEnv would do that and I could then reference it with process.env or import.meta.env

Ah, i think I might have got confused. It works when setting the env vars explicitly with yarn dev, just not from the .env file?

If you console.log(env) after your loadEnv statement, does the variables appear?

it outputs this after running yarn build:
NODE_ENV: [32m'production'[39m,
BACKEND_URL: [32m'http://localhost:8080'[39m,
which is weird, because my env file says NODE_ENV should be development, but I guess yarn build is building for production ? but then in the same process the console.log statement I already had is still saying it's undefined from process.env

Ok, so it looks like the .env file is being read. Try changing VITE_BACKEND_URL: JSON.stringify(env.VITE_BACKEND_URL) to __TEST_URL__: JSON.stringify(env.VITE_BACKEND_URL) then in your code where you "load it in" simply check if __TEST_URL__ has been defined. It looks like you're trying to re-read from the environment again, but for sure changing the names will help you distinguish what it is you're actually reading. I think you may be shadowing your defined variable with a locally declared one that is attempting to read a process.env that hasn't been set.

I haven't managed to make a full reproducible example, but what follows is what I believe is happening. It's a confusion I've made myself.
Let's say you have an environment file:
VITE_BACKEND_URL=http://localhost:8080

You can load this Using Environment Variables in Config and then define global constant replacements
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => {
  // Load env file based on `mode` in the current working directory.
  // Set the third parameter to '' to load all env regardless of the `VITE_` prefix.
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), '')
  return {
    // vite config
    define: {
      __VITE_BACKEND_URL__: JSON.stringify(env.VITE_BACKEND_URL),
    },
  }
})

As per the docs, if you're using TypeScript you will need to declare your global constants
// vite-env.d.ts
declare const __VITE_BACKEND_URL__: string


:warning: Note that this is a different method to using process.env. You can also access environment variables through process.env if those variables have been set.

When you do something like this:
NODE_ENV="development" BACKEND_URL="http://localhost:8080" yarn dev

You are making the environment variables available via process.env but this is not the same as declaring a global constant using vite.

What your code does (I suspect)
// destructure process.env and shadow the global variables defined by vite
const {
  NODE_ENV,
  VITE_BACKEND_URL,
} = process.env;

// Where loadEnv was used, and environment variables not explicitly set, this will be undefined
console.log('BACKEND_URL from process.env:', VITE_BACKEND_URL)

// everything below will just use what was set above
const env = {
  NODE_ENV: NODE_ENV || 'development',
  BACKEND_URL: VITE_BACKEND_URL,
};

export type ProjectEnv = typeof env;

export default () => ({
  data: env,
});

Instead, you can simply use global constants
console.log('BACKEND_URL *not* from process.env:', __VITE_BACKEND_URL__)

To avoid confusion use the double underscore convention when defining globals.
If you want to use process.env then you would want some method for making sure your variables in .env are set in the process environment. You don't appear to be doing this atm.
Using import.meta is another approach but I'd have to look at that again to remind myself of the details and I don't think it'd explain what was happening in your current setup.

Okay, so this has led to some behavior that I am confused by.  I did exactly as you said, having VITE_BACKEND_URL in my .env file, using the double underscore in the definition file, and adding the type declaration to vite-env.d.ts.  However, when I try and set something to equal VITE_BACKEND_URL I get a runtime error that it is undefined, and when I run console.log(VITE_BACKEND_URL) from the browser i get two outputs for some reason, which is localhost:8080 on one line and then undefined on the other.  I'm not really sure why that'd be.

import.meta.env is also just undefined for some reason

Once you have defined the global as __VITE_BACKEND_URL__ that is what you need to use in your code. VITE_BACKEND_URL will be undefined, that's just what was in your .env file and loaded by vite config... but it is the global constant available in your code. This is what you should log console.log(__VITE_BACKEND_URL__)

Oh yeah, I meant that but stack overflow interpreted my double underscore as bolding the text, my bad lol

Okay so I figured it out I think.  The other extra stuff in my code was basically overriding it ?  I didn't even need to set a global variable, just to directly reference it with import.meta.env.

@user20134455 Glad you got it fixed. Ah, yeah, those backticks come in handy: \VITE_BACKEND_URL``
